# Facebook API: How to make batch request using Facebook Graph Explorer?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to get likes and comments of multiple posts in one http request using post Id. I was trying to do this using Facebook Graph Explorer. How do I get this data in one request in graph explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
/?ids={post_id},{post_id}&fields=likes,comments
```

where `{post_id}` is a single post id.

Comment: that did it. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any limit on how many post ids i can send in one request?

Comment: AFAIK there is none documented, but keep in mind the URL length, and that you'll likely receive a timeout if the results need too long to render on the Graph API side. Also, you'll need to take care of pagination I guess...